# Flutter how to use where method in dynamic array

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use where method in dynamic array. I am getting data from api and i want to find some data from the response with the help of where method.

Following are the repsonse of api.

```
[
    {
      'status': true,
      'result': 'found',
      'data': [
        {
          'id': 10676487174744,
          'name': 'Taki Rajani',
          'email': 'mohamtaki.rai@gmail.com',
          'isAdmin': false,
          'description': 'ta rai'
        },
        {
          'id': 1172269813061229,
          'name': 'Aar Raj',
          'email': 'rajnia@gmail.com',
          'isAdmin': false,
          'description': 'test'
        },
        {
          'id': 12854121,
          'name': 'testing',
          'email': 'testing1222@gmail.com',
          'isAdmin': false,
          'description': 'details'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

following are my code for finding same user id which i was stored in storeUserID variable.

**2 problems:-
1)when i print listof user, I am getting all datas in my case 3 data but *when I print length of this list the reponse shows count only 1*.
2)"where" method is showing nothing on print might be is not working.**

```
Future<GetUserData> getUserDetail() async {
    var url = "https://aeliya.mydomin.com/getUser.php";
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var jsondata = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    List listOfUser = [];

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      //print(jsondata);
      listOfUser.add(jsondata);
      print(listOfUser);
      print(listOfUser.length);
      var findid = listOfUser.where((element) => element == storeUserID);
      print(findid);
      return GetUserData.fromJson(jsondata);
    } else {
      return GetUserData.fromJson(jsondata);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your api response contain a list and inside that the data contains the list you want. So change this:

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  //print(jsondata);
  listOfUser.add(jsondata);
  print(listOfUser);
  print(listOfUser.length);
  var findid = listOfUser.where((element) => element == storeUserID);
  print(findid);
  return GetUserData.fromJson(jsondata);
} else {
  return GetUserData.fromJson(jsondata);
}
```

to this:

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  
  print(jsondata['data']);
  print(jsondata['data'].length);
  var findid = (jsondata['data'] as List)
    .where((element) => element['id'] == 1172269813061229);
  print(findid);
  return GetUserData.fromJson(jsondata['data']);
} else {
  return GetUserData.fromJson(jsondata['data']);
}
```

Comment: not working, I am getting following error Tried calling: []("data")

Comment: could you show me the result of print('jsondata = $jsondata');?

Comment: {
    "status": true,
    "result": "found",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "106764933065187174744",
            "name": "Taki Rajani",
            "email": "mohammadtaki.rajani@gmail.com",
            "isAdmin": "false",
            "description": "taki rajani"
        },
        {
            "id": "1221",
            "name": "testing",
            "email": "testing1222@gmail.com",
            "isAdmin": "false",
            "description": "details"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out. @TakiRajani

Comment: E/flutter (28241): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
E/flutter (28241): #0      new GetUserData.fromJson (package:mahuva_azadari/Models/getUserData.dart:16:19)
E/flutter (28241): #1      _AdminReqState.getUserDetail (package:mahuva_azadari/Screens/Admin%20Request.dart:337:26)
E/flutter (28241): <asynchronous suspension>

but sir i am not understood this warning can see this please

Answer (score 0):

> when I print length of this list the reponse shows count only 1

its because here `listOfUser.add(jsondata);` you are adding the whole response body. and your response body is 1 object.

---

> "where" method is showing nothing on print might be is not working.

you list is not a `User` list,  thats why this condition `element == storeUserID` in your `where` method will always false. And if its false, then it will return  nothing.

---

workaround:

```
...
var jsondata = jsonDecode(response.body); // do not make it to String. Your response is a LIST
List listOfUser = [];
 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   // i assume your response will only have 1 object
   final data = jsondata[0]['data'];
   listOfUser.add(data);
   final findid  = listOfUser.where((element) => element['id'] == storeUserID);
   print(findid);
  return GetUserData();
  // return GetUserData.fromJson(jsondata); you have to make sure this is not error. its because your response is an array. not a Map
 }else{

 throw Exception(response.body);
 }
...
```

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("data")
Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:38:5)
AdminReqState.getUserDetail (package:mahuva_azadari/Screens/Admin%20Request.dart:332:31)